# How to make partial copy of objects in Java?

Tags: java, shallow-copy

I have a class and two instances. I want to make partial copy of objects.

```
public class Testing{

    String name;
    String subject;

}

Testing test1 = new Testing();
test1.setName("myName");
test1.setSubject("mySubject");

Testing test2 = test1; 
test1.setName("newName");
test1.setSubject("newSubject");
```

Here is the output.

```
Printing test1
Name: newName
Subject: newSubject

Printing test2
Name: newName
Subject: newSubject
```

What I want is test1 to retain its name while letting test2 to modify rest of the members such that whenver test2 modifies any variable, it is reflected in test1 (except name). Is there anyway to achieve this functionality?

Desired output:

```
Printing test1
Name: myName
Subject: newSubject

Printing test2
Name: newName
Subject: newSubject
```

Comment: If you wanted to model a student with several subjects, you can create a class `Student` and an attribute that represents the list of subjects (`List` of `Subject` objects).

Comment: Create a new object. You're referencing a single object, the same object, with your variables test1 and test2.

Comment: If I use, test2 = new Testing(), test2.setName("newSubject"). How "newSubject" will be set for test1? I don't want to do it manually for all objects.

Comment: Its best to think of java (object) variables as holding house addresses. Once you have the address you can post instructions to the house (object). If you copy the address onto annother piece of paper (variable) letters still go to the same house

Comment: You should create a clone method for the object, it can copy the contents of the object into a new object rather that copying the reference to a single object. Java doesn't provide this "out of the box" because the meaning of copy can vary from object to object

Comment: Are you really asking how to set a default value?  Please try to clarify the ultimate goal here.  Say you created 100 different students.  Would you want `student1.setSubject("xyz")` to update all 100 students' `subject` values?  Or are you just trying to set an initial default value for `subject`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like the OP wants some kind of template to save having to re-enter information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to split it into two classes. `test1` and `test2` will need to be different objects that contain another object that is shared between them. In the code below I call that shared object `Details`.

**`Testing`**

```
class Testing {

    String name;
    final Details details;

    private Testing(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    Testing() {
        this(new Details());
    }

    Testing copy() {
        return new Testing(details);
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.details.subject = subject;
    }

    String asString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s\n%s", name, details.asString());
    }
}
```

**`Details`**

```
class Details {

    String subject;

    String asString() {
        return String.format("Subject: %s", subject);
    }
}
```

**Test runner**

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Testing test1 = new Testing();
        test1.setName("myName");
        test1.setSubject("mySubject");

        Testing test2 = test1.copy();
        test2.setName("newName");
        test2.setSubject("newSubject");

        System.out.println(String.format(
            "Printing test1\n%s\n\nPrinting test2\n%s",
            test1.asString(),
            test2.asString()
        ));
    }
}
```

**Test output**

```
Printing test1
Name: myName
Subject: newSubject

Printing test2
Name: newName
Subject: newSubject
```

Comment: For the record, I think this is an awful design, and I don't condone mutable data structures, but this is what OP asked for.

Comment: Can you please explain why this is a bad design? and how it can be improved..hints, may be?

Comment: I'd need to know at a higher level what you're trying to achieve. But most things can/should be done without mutation (though a lot of the "java community" will disagree with me here).

Comment: To be specific, this Testing class represents a SymbolTableEntry in my static analysis program. Whenever two objects (test1, test2 for example) in the analyzed code refer to the same location, I need to maintain two SymbolTableEntry entries with different names...does this info help or need more information? Above code seems to give me the right solution...

Comment: Here's how I might design that: Give the symbol table a multimap from location to entry, let there be two entries that don't share any mutable data structures, and when you need to update them both, just update them both.